# Iterating over a list in JSON using TypeScript

Tags: json, list, typescript

I'm having a problem iterating over my json in TypeScript. I'm having trouble with one specific json field, the `tribe`. For some reason I can't iterate over that one. In the debugger, I'm expecting the `Orc` to show up but instead I get a `0`. Why is this? How do I iterate correctly over my `tribe` data?

```
// Maps a profession or tribe group name to a bucket of characters
let professionMap = new Map<string, Character[]>()
let tribeMap = new Map<string, Character[]>()

let herolistJson = require('./data/HeroList.json')

for (let hero of herolistJson){

  // Certain characters can have more than one tribe
  // !!!!! The trouble begins here, tribe is 0???
  for (let tribe in hero.tribe){
    let tribeBucket = tribeMap.get(tribe) as Character[]

    // If the hero does not already exist in this tribe bucket, add it
    if(tribeBucket.find(x => x.name == hero.name) === undefined )
    {
      tribeBucket.push(new Character(hero.name, hero.tribe, hero.profession, hero.cost))
    }
  }
}
```

My json file looks like this

```
[
  { 
    "name": "Axe", 
    "tribe": ["Orc"], 
    "profession": "Warrior",
    "cost": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Enchantress",
    "tribe": ["Beast"],
    "profession": "Druid",
    "cost": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over the *keys* of an object, not the values.  The keys of an array are its indices.  If you use [`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead, you'll use the newer iterator protocol and an [Array's iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) provides values instead of keys.

```
for (let tribe of /* in */ hero.tribe) {
```

Note, that this won't work in IE 11, but will work in most other browsers as well many JS environments that are ES2015 compatible. [kangax/compat](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) has a partial list.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "in" to "of" in second loop.